# Can't remove a user from Outlook 2003 delegates

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I need to remove one of my assistants from my delegates in Outlook 2003 but it won't remove them. When I go into delegates, I delete the user then hit Apply and OK; if I come back, that user is still there.

Is there something I can do on my end to remove the user? I don't have access to the Exchange server at the moment.

Comment: You mean you are not connected to the Exchange server, or you can't go to the Exchange System Manager?

Comment: I can't connect into the Management console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, rules and other similar settings get goofed up. Try opening Outlook with this from the Run box: `outlook /cleanrules`. Then try if it is not already gone.

This may also be relevant:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813929/

I will keep the rest of the original answer as it may be helpful to someone down the road.

By their very nature, delegate information is stored on the Exchange server, otherwise, if you were not connected, how would it know who to authorize in your absence?

So you cannot delete them until you are connected, and your Outlook can update the removal on the Exchange Server.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/about-delegate-access-HP005242136.aspx

Comment: I'm online, connected with Exchange. I just can't connect to the Management console.

Comment: I added to the answer, hopefully one or the other will do it for you. If not, post back with any more details you cna provide.

Comment: Worked fine. I also managed on the Exchange server, finaly! Thanks a lot.